# Include Bootstrap 5 Using jQuery Into WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to upgrade from Bootstrap 4.6 to Bootstrap 5.0 into my WordPress theme. Below is how I include BS 5, jQuery and some custom JS file.

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/min/build.min.js', array() );
        }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

This is how I initiate jQuery in the separate file:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // Do Something;
});
```

- As long as I was using BS 4.6 all was working fine but since I have upgraded to BS 5 the **Accordion Component** doesn't work anymore. It works only if I disable jQuery.
- I don't get any console error.
- I have updated all the BS components according to the new documentation. In fact all work but the **[Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/)** one.
- I am aware that BS 5 works better with Vanilla JS but for now I need both BS 5 and jQuery.

Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: A quick and dirty test is to load up your ```bootstrap.bundle.min.js``` on the head section instead of the footer section. I know it's odd but it happens. Sometimes, some components need the javascript file immediately in order to work properly. Try something like this: ```wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), "5.1", false );```. Notice the ```false``` at the end of your enqueue.

Comment: @Ruvee ...thanks for the suggestion. I tried but unfortunately it didn't work. It works if I load the non minified js `wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/index.js', array() );` Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're aware that there's a typo at the end of this line:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery) );
```

but just in case, the correction is:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery') );
```

Comment: thanks, I am aware of it...there is no typo in the real code